# Diagnosis for Kaori in "Your lie in April"

Tags: manga, your-lie-in-april

The character [Kaori](http://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.wikia.com/wiki/Kaori_Miyazono) in the "[Your Lie in April](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Lie_in_April)" has an illness.

> she dies of it.

As far as I can tell, it is not stated what it is.  Did I miss it?

Symptoms:

- > when she was very young she needed surgery
- > her surgery is related to her falling down in 7th grade.
- > she behaves in ways that are atypical for her.  Sometimes female characters are played as mercurial, so this may or may not be a valid symptom.
- > she fell at the recital, after she played
- > she had paralysis in her legs, (likely accompanied peripheral neuropathy)
- > her parents knew it was terminal about a year before she died.
- > she regularly went to the hospital for treatment but has not (where I am in the series) lost her hair (suggesting no chemotherapy.)
- > the (alleged) color of the paths at the hospital (Totsuhara University hospital) are either green or white.
- > She could not control the twitching of her right hand, and that would make playing violin impossible.

Some others have suggested that the diagnosis is a variation on

> ALS or prion disease.

Is there a reference that tells or at least gives strong support to say what the illness was?

It is likely this series is an

- > [Utsuge](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Utsuge) trope

**Update (speculation):**

- > It may be that as a young child she had an [astrocytoma](http://www.abta.org/brain-tumor-information/types-of-tumors/astrocytoma.html) (particular kind of brain cancer) for which the tumor was removed, and they thought it was complete, but either it returned or wasn't all caught.  If so then it would have advanced, possibly into a [secondary glioblastoma](http://www.abta.org/brain-tumor-information/types-of-tumors/glioblastoma.html) (stage 4 variation, very lethal, and has average time between diagnosis and end of quality of life of ~18 mo.)

Comment: Unlikely to be als or prion disease as a last ditch treatment involved risky surgery.  Maybe a brain tumor, as symptoms can be paralysis and muscle weakness?  Personally though, I think it was yet another case of "more beautiful until you die" disease.

Comment: ALS would make it impossible to play the violin.

Comment: There are advanced stages of astrocytoma's that that, if not detected early, become glioma's that have high mortality rates and some of the phenomena observed in the character.

Answer (score 1):

the actual disease kaori had in the anime is Myeloid Bone Marrow cancer, it is treatable when the person is young and is survivable but only if it DOESN'T come back!

if the cancer "Relapses" the person's likelihood of survival drops to a measly 17% with proper treatment and surgery (which often leads to a secondary relapse and no survival rate at all!)

Evidence: she mentions she has anemia, bone marrow deficiency can cause ALS like symptoms (I.E: weakness in limbs, especially the legs)

normally myeloid bone marrow cancer is almost completely survivable when the subject is young (if you are 7 you are more likely to survive the procedure over being 70)

Comment: Is this confirmed, or is this your informed speculation?

Comment: it's not 100% confirmed but according to many speculations this is with a 73% probability: her condition, though other diseases exist this one is most probable because of her "surgery" at age 7 (which is very common with Myeloid Bone Marrow Cancer) and if anything bone marrow cancer that relapses has the same effect!

Comment: CORRECTION: according to new found information it is **CONFIRMED** she had bone marrow disease (so I wasn't far off!) Backing Evidence: the change in pigmentation combined with aforementioned symptoms and also the confusing thing about the end is.....she didn't survive the operation but they cut away to dwell on the more positive ending (a bit of closure to make things at least a little better!)

Comment: Great! Add that information to your post, properly cited, and I guarantee you'll get some upvotes.

Comment: [link] (http://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:4954) the evidence is buried under layers upon layers of speculation but the root cause is finally ruled out!             **P.S:** I also bought the blu-ray and the entire manga series out of my deep feelings for kaori.....she was carefree, full of life!   she lived life to its highest height. i have taken it upon myself to become passionate about music!

Comment: [Kevin Nyaa on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLhAHDJy3Bc&feature=youtu.be) has a video that tries to speak to this.